# Where to find free tutorials about trading algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, algorithmic-trading

I would like to find some tutorial about the trading algorithms like
Iceberg, Dagger, Guerrilla etc.
I have just found some non-free or marketing sites on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the list of references here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_trading

However, actual algorythmic details are unlikely to be published widely - organizations who need to know can pay for research.